# Valid numpy arrays produces IndexError:

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am working on gfs weather data to plot certain parameters using python and matplotlib. Since it is a grib2 file, I am using wgrib2 for extracting data from file (even though I am aware of pygrib). These extracted variables (lat, lon and temp) are convered in to numpy arrary successfully. I am attaching these [lat](https://www.mediafire.com/file/rg0lq5nwrd6zhmr/lat.txt), [lon](https://www.mediafire.com/file/dewkchc8ii44n0i/lon.txt) and [data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bdaay6t9rjmfmt2/data.txt) values for your review. Portion of the code I am using for plotting is:-

```
lat = # load from attached lat file
lon = # load from attached lon file
data = # load data from data file
plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lat_ts=10, llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max(),
            resolution='c')
x, y = m(lat, lon)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, data)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
plt.show()
```

Now, when I use matplotlib `countorf` function for plotting, it produces the following error:-

```
File "wgrib2.py", line 145, in <module>
    cs = m.contourf(x, y, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 521, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3644, in contourf
    xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Here is the minimal example as requested (actual files are uploaded in above link):-

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, division
import os
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lat = np.loadtxt("lat.txt")
lon = np.loadtxt("lon.txt")
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lat_ts=10, llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max(),
            resolution='c')
x, y = m(lat, lon)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, data)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
plt.show()
```

**Edit 1**

Uploaded files again.

It appears to be an issue with dimension of the data. The output generate by wgrib2 to numpy array is a single dimension with value of (259920,) for lat, lon and data. I have checked with pygrib and it produces the shape of (720, 361) which leads to 720 x 361 = 259920. Therefore, it seems that I have an issue with the data being converted in to numpy.

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] that doesn't rely on external data. Just use something "like it" but shorter. Maybe `np.random.random()` can help? Also what is `Basemap`?

Comment: Judging by `x.shape[0]/2`, it looks like you've installed a Python 2 package on Python 3.

Comment: @ user2357112, I have not used pip for this. This is the default install using package manager, pacman,  under Arch Linux.

Comment: pacman is installing an outdated version, apparently 1.0.7. The latest basemap toolkit version has a fix for this.

Comment: As long as it requires reading from files it's neither minimal nor complete. Please try to emulate the dataset by using custom arrays, i.e. `np.random.random` or such like.

Comment: The links seem to be broken. Without [mcve] there is little one can do to help.

Comment: Corrected the link. and edited the question again. The reason for uploading the actual data is that I am unable to reproduce the same data through code.

Comment: If your error is the result of the data not being loaded properly, and you haven't given us the information necessary to load the data, then we can't answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not produce an error on Python 3.5 with basemap 1.1.0, so this should be fixed if you upgrade your basemap. If you are actually running Python 2 (which is suggested by your minimal example), then it may be sufficient to remove `division` from your `__future__` imports.

In particular, this MCVE does not produce an error:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, 180)
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, 360)
lat, lon = np.meshgrid(lat, lon)
data = np.random.randn(360, 180)
plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lat_ts=10, llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max(),
            resolution='c')
x, y = m(lon, lat)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, data)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
plt.show()
```

If for some reason that doesn't work and you want to patch the issue erroring right here, you can go into the `basemap` source code and change `xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]` to xx = `x[int(x.shape[0]/2),:]`. What I heard from Ben suggests that if you do this, you're likely to continue to run in to other compatibility problems (possibly right after you make that fix), but it *might* get this code working for now.

Keep in mind that `basemap` does not support Python 3, and is deprecated. The core developer of Basemap (Ben Root) is urging users to stop using it, because it's been abandoned and will not be ported to Python 3, even when Python 2 stops receiving security updates in 2020. He suggests using `cartopy` instead. All this was said by Ben Root at Scipy 2017.

Comment: The fact that Basemap will not be maintained further than 2020 does not mean that it should not be working now. Unless you know of any reason that the above code is not supposed to work with basemap and python 3, I don't think that this is a useful answer.

Comment: I'm just passing on information from the core developer. Everything I said is objectively true (I'm saying what it was that they said). And that line erroring clearly has a 2/3 compatibility issue.

Comment: So the solution is to install the newest version of basemap and that is it. If basemap is going to be continued in the future is totally irrelevant here (you may of course add a comment if you urgently want people to know that).

Comment: I don't know that installing the newest version will actually fix this issue (someone else said it would), but yes, that suggestion is included in my answer after edits. I've also included the specific code edit to basemap required to fix this problem (for this line).

I think it is valid to say "you shouldn't use deprecated functions or features" in an answer.

Comment: Nobody forces you to give an answer, if you don't know the answer. To be fair, you cannot know the answer, because the question as it is does not allow to be answered (we don't know the code and the versions in use). This doesn't mean that one should desperately try to answer anyways, but simply stay away from it or leave relevant information as comment. As of now this answer consists of an irrelevant part, a part which is surely not the recommended solution (patching the source), and a part where there is no certainty about from your side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154813/discussion-between-jeremy-mcgibbon-and-importanceofbeingernest).